# Php and HTML in the same file, or separate files?

Tags: php, html, file

I've been reading online that it is not a good idea to put HTML and PHP in the same file. Why is that?Is that such a big deal? If so, why and how exactly can you separate the files?

Comment: Depending on the size of your project can make your decisions for you.  A few pages of mainly HTML website would be overkill with a full MVC application with a template engine (IMHO) and yet a larger site with a lot of processing can be a nightmare without an MVC approach.  I've voted to close as opinion based, but it could also be a bit to broad without more understanding of what your trying to do.

Comment: Basically it's all about testability and maintainability. If your app gets complicated you can end up with lots of spaghetti code where you cannot see the wood for the trees. If you include some database query right alongside the HTML used to present the results then it is hard to re-use that query elsewhere when you later need the same functionality on another page. And if there's a big it's hard to test whether the query or the HTML is at fault, because you can't unit test the query function.

Comment: And if you decide to change the page layout or add a new bit, it might be hard to do so without untangling all the associated business logic from what's already there - whereas if you move all logic which doesn't directly relate to presentation into separate classes and functions then you can change and test those different parts in isolation. Lastly, if you work together with other developers on the project you want the code to be clear and easy to understand when reading each others work, and also be able to easily divide work between you without conflicting changes occurring.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're the only one who modify it, it your code and you know what you're doing. it problem is code maintainance would be difficult because of spagetti. Another raison is security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to separate HTML and PHP code is using MVC design pattern, MVC architecture apply the method of separating code in `Model` `View` And `Controller`.

> MVC is an architectural pattern commonly used for developing user interfaces
>   that divides an application into three interconnected parts. This is done to 
>   separate internal representations of information from the ways information is 
>   presented to and accepted from the user. The MVC design pattern decouples these
>   major components allowing for efficient code reuse and parallel development.
>
> > Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Basically, All code about database would be in the model, View in the view, and code bahavior in controller.

In a view you need just data and display it in the view, and some if statement.

There's a lot PHP framework who using MVC design pattern like [Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), [Symfony](https://symfony.com/), etc... They use template view for rendering the view.

Comment: "best" is a statement of opinion, not fact. Don't get me wrong, I think MVC is a great pattern but it's not the only way to organise an application, and I doubt you can quote any hard evidence to day it's actually the best (you also didn't say by what measures you think it's better). This site is supposed to be for hard technical info, not a discussion forum. Please let's not promulgate opinion as fact...there's enough of that kind of nonsense on the internet already. It's enough to state that MVC is one commonly used way to separate concerns in your code, but not the "best". Thanks

Comment: Also let's be clear that MVC (or any other pattern) does not entirely separate the code from the HTML, as the question mentions. That would be impossible, unless the pages never changed their content or data. There will always be code inside the view to control the appearance of the page to some extent. What MVC is good at is separating the code controlling the presentation from the code controlling the business logic, and separating that again from the data structures.

Comment: Lastly the question actually asks _why_ separating code from HTML is a good idea, but you have simply recommended a way of doing it, without answering the underlying question.

Answer (score 0):

as per to your question, its all about design: a good design provides you maintainable code, and it lowers errors occurring possibility in your application.
It's OK to practice PHP with a spagetti coded file, but when you need to write a real life application you should consider using [MVC framework](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2013/12/06/JavaScript-MVC-frameworks.html) (such like [codeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/) or [laravel](https://laravel.com/)) so you can easily get your application in shape.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your how, one popular method is to use output buffering and templating.

For example, if you are in the controller of a MVC framework, you would use a function to select a template and pass the template data.

You would receive a request in your controller.  Someone wants to visit the contact page.  You would do any checks you need (like see if they submitted a form, validate data, etc), and then select the template and pass it any necessary data

```
// Controller
contact($request) {
    if (empty($_POST)) {
        inc('contact-form', ['title' => 'Contact Page'])
    } else {
        inc('contact-thank-you', ['title' => 'Thanks for submitting!']);
    }
}
```

You would use a function like the one below to select a template from a preset directory, and then extract the variables.  This makes them available to your template (DONT EXTRACT $_GET or $_POST)

```
// Function to load template and output it
// Select a path and any variables
function inc($path, $variables, $print = true) {
    $output = NULL;
    $full_path = __DIR__ . "/views/{$path}.php";

    if (file_exists($full_path)) {
        // Extract variables
        extract($variables);

        // Output Buffer
        ob_start();

        // Include
        include $full_path;

        $output = ob_get_clean();
    }

    if ($print) {
        print $output;
    }

    return $output;
}

// Inside templates/about.php
<main>
    <header>
        <h1>
            <?= $title ?>
        </h1>
    </header>
</main>
```